# How to check the webpart performance?

Tags: performance, sharepoint, testing, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

i have a sharepoint site ,in the webpart page i have around 10 webparts.I would like to check 
the performance of individual webpart.i mean which webpart taking more time in the page.
Let me know how can i get this.

Answer (score 3):

Use the **Developer Dashboard**.

- [Using the Developer Dashboard in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/10/28/using-the-developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)
- [Developer Dashboard in SharePoint 2010](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/05/developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2010.html)

Comment: i did the same using SPMonitoredScope.but i guess this will be usefull for perticular function/code...other than this can we achieve the same ?

Comment: @Govind: Can you explain exactly what you want to check? I'm not sure why Developer Dashboard and `SPMonitoredScope` don't satisfy your needs.